# Register type factories with convention

Tags: castle-windsor

Can you register type factories by convention?
got this far and can't find a way to say .AsFactory()

```
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Classes
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .InNamespace("Core.Factories", true)
            );
```

This may not be doable but would prefer to not have register every factory by hand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Configure` when using convention configuration; this lets you pass a lambda that is then called for each component matching the convention: just call `AsFactory` in the lambda

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromThisAssembly()
        .InNamespace("Core.Factories", true)
        .Configure(c => c.AsFactory())
);
```

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity I had to use Types instead of classes so the factories that Typed Factory would get picked up too. I knew about configure but didn't think to do it that way, EPIC!